# configure: error: package not installed, but a package with the same name is installed

Tags: yum, autotools, autoconf

## Introduction

I'm trying to build a repo I recently cloned.

I've run `./autogen.sh`.

I try to run:

```
./configure --enable-project=my-proj --prefix=${HOME}/my-dir
```

`configure` then does lots of checks and then fails with the following output:

```
configure: error: miglayout not installed
```

If I do a `yum install miglayout` (I'm running RHEL7), I get the following:

```
Package miglayout-4.2-5.el7.myproj.7.10.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

## Question

What would be causing `configure` to not see the `miglayout-4.2-5.el7.myproj.7.10.noarch` package I installed as fulfilling its requirement for `miglayout`?

Comment: It's impossible to say from the information given.  The diagnostic from `configure` appears to be custom, so you would need to have a look at the `configure.ac` to determine under what circumstances it might be emitted.  You may also get some clues from `configure.log`.

Comment: ITYM `config.log`

Comment: Yes, `config.log`, sorry.